# What are the lyrics at the end of Ojos De Brujo's Piedras Contra Tanques

Tags: traducción, letras-de-canciones

There are some lyrics at the end of the live version of Ojos De Brujo's [Piedras Contra Tanques on Spotify](http://open.spotify.com/track/2naSnpDK6FPuUIanGJqFMT) That I'm having trouble translating.

It is during the Salsa jam at the end. It's something like;

```
Camino lo, (or it could be Termino Lo)
Romper cajón,
*undecipherable*,
Camino lo.
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Camínalo,
>   rompe el cajón,
>   saca los cuadros,
>   camínalo

Comment: absolute gibberish :D

Comment: It is indeed! This pronunciation is common in the southern regions of Spain (Andalucía) were the final 's' sound is muted

Comment: Yo no oigo "saca los cuadros", sino "saca los cueros". "Saca los cuadros", además, no tiene ningún sentido ni relación con el tema de la canción.

Answer (score 1):

> Camínalo,
>   rompe el cajón,
>   saca los **cueros**,
>   camínalo

"[Sacar los cueros](http://faustolupera.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/los-cueros-al-sol.html)" es una expresión parecida a la castellana "tirar de la manta", "airear los trapos sucios", o "sacar a la luz".

La canción habla de libertad y de la corrupción política, etc. Esa expresión tiene mucho sentido.